# jest coverageDirectory configuration for project inside monorepo

Tags: jestjs, monorepo

I have a typescript monorepo with jest. Their `jest.config.js` is

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  projects: ['<rootDir>/packages/**/jest.config.js'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: [
    "text-summary",
    "lcov",
  ],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['*.spec.ts', '*.spec.tsx']
}
```

At the `server` package I create the `jest.config.js` with

```
const { name } = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  displayName: name,
  name,
  'transform': {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts'
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/packages/server/src/tests/coverage',
}
```

But when I run jest it creates the `coverage` directory at the root of my monorepo.

I just try to use `coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/src/tests/coverage',`, `coverageDirectory: 'src/tests/coverage',` and `coverageDirectory: [__dirname, 'src', 'tests', 'coverage'].join('/'),` without success.

The only way I could change the path of coverage directory was to specify it at the `jest.config.js` of the monorepo, but with this I am unable to specify a coverage directory to each project.

Somebody knows how can I specify a different coverage directory for each project at a monorepo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only specify a different coverage directory for each project if you are running jest for each product individually. If you are using a global config (the jest.config.js at the root of your monorepo) then the same coverage settings are applied across them all, including the coverage output directory.

Comment: what about different project setup (ie: using "projects" prop) in the jest.config.ts globla? it seems to get overrided either way, the doc does not mention what you are stating (your statement is true though)

Comment: is this still true in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation with jest@29.7.0 and I experienced the same as you: only the global `jest.config.js`'s `coverageDirectory` is taken into account. Overriding it in project configs made no difference, regardless of what I did with the global config.

I couldn't find a way to make this work while running test projects one at a time. One project would overwrite the other. I'm not sure how we're intended to use this feature, but what worked for me was using environment variables to override the global `coverageDirectory` path on a per-command basis.

In `package.json`:

```json
"test:all": "jest",
"test:package-a": "COVERAGE_DIR=coverage/package-a jest --selectProjects PackageA",
"test:package-b": "COVERAGE_DIR=coverage/package-b jest --selectProjects PackageB",
```

In `jest.config.js`:

```js
const coverageDir = process.env.COVERAGE_DIR || 'coverage/unified';

module.exports = {
  coverageDirectory: `<rootDir>${coverageDir}`,
}
```

With this, you can run either of those three scripts and it will populate coverage directories where you want them. I included `test:all` just for completeness. It feels like an antipattern, but this was the only way I found to run projects one at a time and have the results go to different directories.